# Numeric comparison failure in a switch statement

Tags: javascript

"original post" : *This function should compare the value of 'a' with several other values, but always defaults. My test shows that the value of 'a' or 'b' is never changed.  Do I have the case a > statement incorrect or elsewhere?*

Now I understand that I can not use comparison in the case statement:

Should I use a bunch of if statements and a while (a <> = 0) to do the multiple checking and decrementing?

The snippit below shows 'a' with a particular value.  In the full function, actually 'a' gets a value from a random number in another function.  It must be checked against 16 possible values and decremented, then rechecked until it finally reaches 0.  The comparison values are actually powers of 2 (1 through 16).

```
    function solution() {        
    var a = 18000;
    var b = 0;

    switch (a) {
    case a > 30000:
        a = a - 30000;
        b = b++;
        break;
    case a > 16000:
        b = b++; a = a - 16000;
        break;
    case a > 8000:
        b = b++; a = a - 8000;
        break;
    default:
        c = "defaulted!, Why?";
        break;   
    } 

    window.alert (a + " " + b + " " + c); 
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have comparisons in case statements. That's not how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't use boolean expressions in `switch` case labels. You'll need to rewrite the code as a series of `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use switch for range checks like this. It's possible with

```
switch (true) {
case (a > 30000):
    a = a - 30000;
    b = b++;
```

but just don't do that.

Use if/else instead. While switch is really just an abstract if/else construct, use it for things like this:

```
switch(a){
case 1: ...
}
```